# Ios beacon monitoring didEnterRegion event fires only "on the ipad" even if i set desiredAccuracy and distanceFilter fields to 100 meters

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, beacon

In the below code, i set the fields **desiredAccuracy** and **distanceFilter** to **100**. But it does not works as it should. As i mention on title, When i put beacon on ipad, didEnterRegion fires, when i take back, after about 15 seconds, **didExitRegion** fires. Am i missing something?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h" 
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface AppDelegate() <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL dropEmptyRanges;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (instancetype)init
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;

  }

  return self;
}

-(CLBeaconRegion *) createBeaconRegion: (NSString *) identifier
                                  uuid: (NSString *) uuid
                                 major: (NSInteger) major
                                 minor:(NSInteger) minor
{
  NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuid];

  unsigned short mj = (unsigned short) major;
  unsigned short mi = (unsigned short) minor;

  CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:beaconUUID major:mj
                                                                         minor:mi
                                                                    identifier:identifier];

  NSLog(@"createBeaconRegion with: identifier - uuid - major - minor");
  beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
  beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
  beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

  return beaconRegion;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
  }

  CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [self createBeaconRegion:@"backgroundRegion" uuid:@"fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825" major:10004 minor:5178];

  [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];

  [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];

  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

  if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil]];
  }

  return YES;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didEnterRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
  NSLog(@"Beacon did enter region");
  UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
  localNotification.alertBody = @"Beacon did enter region";
  localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didExitRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
  NSLog(@"Beacon did exit region");
  UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
  localNotification.alertBody = @"Beacon did exit region";
  localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];


}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
       didRangeBeacons: (NSArray *) beacons
              inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{
  NSLog(@"Beacon did range");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately, this technique won't work for limiting beacon detections.**

The fields `locationManager.distanceFilter` and `locationManager.desiredAccuracy` do not apply to beacon detections.  These only have any effect on callbacks from CoreLocation when getting location updates based on GPS/Cell/WiFi positioning.  The documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423500-distancefilter) says as much:

> This property is used only in conjunction with the standard location services and is not used when monitoring significant location changes.

While that statement sounds a bit vague, what it means by "standard location services" is when you call `startUpdatingLocation` to get these non-beacon location updates.  You can read more about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation).  Although the quote above does not explicitly say so, it would be clearer if it also said "This property is used only in conjunction with the standard location services and is not used when monitoring significant location changes or monitoring beacon regions."

**If you want to limit beacon detections based on distance you can not do so with monitoring APIs.  You must range for the beacons**, get a distance estimate every one second, and only fire your events if you see that the estimated distance is less than your desired threshold.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. I'll try to implement distance detection by ranging beacons after region entrance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not currently ranging any beacons. Try adding the following lines:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didEnterRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
  NSLog(@"Beacon did enter region");
  UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
  localNotification.alertBody = @"Beacon did enter region";
  localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
  [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didExitRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
  NSLog(@"Beacon did exit region");
  UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
  localNotification.alertBody = @"Beacon did exit region";
  localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
  [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Allan, In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, i called the startRangingBeaconsInRegion and startMonitoringForRegion methods. didEnterRegion and didExitRegion works successfully now. I want my app to scan beacon signals in larger area. Now, didEnterRegion fires only too near the ipad. When i change the ipad position little bit, didExitRegion event fires.